# Jasmine unittest. ng-model seems not to update

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test in which i'm testing a directive using $compile. I want to insert some value and see if it's being displayed somewhere else. Yet somehow my test fails! "Expected '' to be 'something'." I've simplyfied the problem as far as possible:

```
define(['angular'],
    function () {
        'use strict';

        describe('test App: ', function () {

            describe('Given x ', function () {

                var $rootScope, $scope, $compile;

                beforeEach(inject(['$injector', function ($injector) {
                    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
                    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
                    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                }]));

                describe('y', function () {

                    it('z', inject(function () {

                        var element = $compile('<div><input type="text" ng-model="foobar"><span>{{foobar}}</span></div>')($scope);
                        $scope.$digest();

                        var inputElement = element.find('input');
                        inputElement.val('something').triggerHandler('input');
                        inputElement.triggerHandler('blur');

                        $scope.$digest();

                        inputElement = element.find('input');
                        expect(inputElement.val()).toBe('something'); // This one succeeds

                        var spanElement = element.find('span');
                        expect(spanElement.html()).toBe('something'); // this one fails
                    }));

                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!